# Real world experiences with the ADO.NET Entity Framework and unit testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, entity-framework

I am investigating the ADO.NET Entity Framework in combination with unit testing. A recommended way is described by Scott Allan:

[Testability and Entity Framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff714955.aspx)

The article involves the [code generation with POCOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx).

My first impression: The manual effort to introduce and maintain this architecture is high. Before a deep dive I am interested in any real world experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using POCO objects makes unit testing easier, but doesn't help you in making the code that uses LINQ queries over those POCO objects testable. Take a look at [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). It describes how to hide EF behind an abstraction, while still allowing to use LINQ queries over it.

Comment: Great article. This is a detailed and valuable elaboration of the theme. The straightforward way you toggle between LINQ to SQL and EF by replacing just a small piece of code and the usage of extension methods on the repository impresses me. And the real world experience - I found some in the comments of your readers.

Comment: If you can, still try using POCO objects. IMO using POCOs together with that given aproach will probably work best. And please don't forget about the short comes mentioned in the article ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Scott suggests the POCO template as an *option*, not a requirement. You don't need to use it. Scott's strategy also works with non-POCO entities.

The effort would be high if unit testing were the only benefit. But since you also get a well structured application organized along commonly-understood patterns, good unit testing is really just icing on the cake with Scott's architecture.

Answer (score 1):

To add what @Craig Stuntz entioned, I'd recommend you take a look at the [EF Futures Code-First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx). It's in CTP5 right now, and RC/Beta soon. I've been using it for two separate projects recently and it's awesome. I personally hate using a visual editor when this should be really driven by the code. I've found POCO to be awesome for writing a project.